# How can make selection is sequence and dynamic by jq

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How I can select a sequence ids for apply "bootstrapNumber" plugin on them

```
$('#qty1').bootstrapNumber();
```

and there are id="qty1",id="qty2",id="qty3",id="qty4"......so on
I want apply this in all qty

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48602425/edit) and make it a lot more clear: what your problem is, what you want to achieve, and what you have tried to achieve that. As it is, your question is (in)complete gibberish to me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to target `qty<someNumber>` you could use the  attribute selector `[]` passing the *Starts-With* `^=` flag

```
$("[id^='qty']").bootstrapNumber();
```

otherwise comma separate your selectors

```
$('#qty1, #qty2, #qty3, #qty4').bootstrapNumber();
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thanks a lot Roko

Comment: @Amee you're welcome. PS: [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)